# How to use mySQL convert_tz functions in Laravel/Lumen query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, convert-tz

```
$result['tests'] = Test::select('test.test_id',
    DB::raw('convert_tz(test.updated_at,+00:00,-05:30) as updated_at'),
    'test.created_at')
    ->orderBy('test.test_id', 'ASC')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

I already find the solution for **CASE WHEN** queries like
**DB::raw('(CASE WHEN favorite.is_favorite IS NULL 
                    THEN 0 ELSE favorite.is_favorite END) AS is_favorite'),**

But the problem is I cannot do the same with **CONVERT_TZ** where the values are inside the quotes.

**DB::raw('convert_tz(test.updated_at,+00:00,-05:30) as updated_at')**

Comment: `DB::raw("convert_tz(test.updated_at,'+00:00','-05:30') as updated_at")`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I already tried it, but not working!

Comment: What exactly? Is there a syntax error? Or is the result wrong?